# Recursive Py Program Returning j=none when j==1?

Tags: python, recursion

Recursive Py Program Returning j=None when j==1?  This does not make sense as base case specified j must equal 1 and does not call function again.

```
import sys
y=10
def decrease(j):
    if j==1:
        print('j =' + str(j) + '(1)')
        print('returning j')
        return j
    else:
        print('j =' + str(j) + '(not 1)')
        print('decreasing j')
        j = j-1
        print('calling decrease j')
        decrease(j)
y=decrease(y)
print('complete')
print(y)
```

Comment: The `else` clause doesn't `return` anything so you will get `None`. Perhaps you meant `return decrease(j)`

Comment: Thank you @AChampion this worked!

Answer (score 1):

You forget to `return decrease(j)` at the end of the second branch.

Usually when you encounter unexpected `None` returned from function, check first that all the branches end with a `return` statement. Without it, the function returns `None`